# Unit testing React component using Material UI Dialog

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, material-ui, reactjs-testutils

I am currently writing unit tests for my React + MaterialUi application.

In my application I have a Dialog. I want to make sure depending on what button pressed on the dialog:

```
<FlatButton
  label="Cancel"
  secondary={true}
  onTouchTap={this._cancelDialog.bind(this)} 
 />
 <FlatButton
   label="Submit"
   primary={true}
   onTouchTap={this._confirmDialog.bind(this)} 
 />
```

that the internal state changes accordingly.

Unfortunately i cannot get ahold of the dialog content using
`TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(FlatButton)`
or
`scryRenderedComponentsWithTag("button")`
and so on.

Any ideas on how that flow can be tested?

**Update 1**

So I can get the Dialog instance by calling TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(Dialog). But I can not get the dialogs content. DOM wise the content does not render inside the view itself. Its rendered in a new created node on document level (div). So i tried this:

```
let cancelButton = window.document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
Simulate.click(cancelButton);
```

cancelButton in the case above is the correct DOM element. Simulate.click however does not trigger the components click function.

regards
Jonas

Comment: could you change your question in a more legible format?

Answer (score 7):

just ran into the same problem. I looked into the source code, and the Dialog component's render method actually creates an instance of the component `RenderToLayer`. this component behaves as a portal and breaks react's DOM tree by returning null in its' render function and instead appending directly to the body.

Luckily, the `RenderToLayer` component accepts the prop `render`, which essentially allows the component to pass to the portal a function to be called when it is in a render cycle. This means that we can actually manually trigger this event ourselves. It's not perfect, i admit, but after a few days of poking around trying to find a solution for this hack i am throwing in the towel and writing my tests like this:

```
var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<UserInteractions.signupDialog show={true}/>)
var dialog = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(component.refs.dialog.renderLayer())
var node = React.findDOMNode(dialog)
```

and here is what my UserInteractions.signupDialog looks like:

```
exports.signupDialog = React.createClass({
...
  render: function() {
    var self = this;

    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          ref='dialog'
          title="Signup"
          modal={false}
          actions={[
            <Button
              label="Cancel"
              secondary={true}
              onTouchTap={self.__handleClose}
            />,
            <Button
              label="Submit"
              primary={true}
              keyboardFocused={true}
              onTouchTap={self.__handleClose}
            />
          ]}
          open={self.props.show}
          onRequestClose={self.__handleClose}
          >
          <div className='tester'>ham</div>
          <TextField id='tmp-email-input' hintText='email' type='text'/>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Now i can make assertions against the child components rendered in the dialog box, and can even make assertions about events bound to my original component, as their relationship is maintained.

I definitely recommend setting up a debugger in your testing stack if you are going to continue using material ui. Theres not a lot of help for things like this. Heres what my debug script looks like:

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers .:./test/utils/compiler.js test/**/*.spec.js",
    "debug": "mocha debug --compilers .:./test/utils/compiler.js test/**/*.spec.js"
  }
}
```

and now you can use `npm test` to run mocha tests, and `npm run debug` to enter debugger. Once in the debugger, it will immediately pause and wait for you to enter breakpoints. At this juncture, enter `c` to continue. Now you can place `debugger;` statements anywhere in your code to generate a breakpoint which the debugger will respond to. Once it has located your breakpoint, it will pause and allow you to engage your code using local scope. At this point, enter `repl` to enter your code's local scope and access your local vars.

Perhaps you didnt need a debugger, but maybe someone else will find this helpful. Good luck, happy coding!

Comment: I've been smoking my head for while to tackle this problem with Dialog testing. Excellent answer. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 5):

Solved it as follows:

```
/*
* I want to verify that when i click on cancel button my showModal state is set * to false
*/

//shallow render my component having Dialog
const wrapper= shallow(<MyComponent store={store} />).dive();

//Set showModal state to true
wrapper.setState({showModal:true});

//find out cancel button with id 'cancelBtn' object from actions and call onTouchTap to mimic button click
wrapper.find('Dialog').props().actions.find((elem)=>(elem.props.id=='cancelBtn')).props.onTouchTap();

//verify that the showModal state is set to false
expect(wrapper.state('showModal')).toBe(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and solve it like that :

```
const myMock = jest.genMockFunction();
const matcherComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <MatcherComponent onClickCancel={myMock} activAction/>
        );
const raisedButton = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(
            matcherComponent, RaisedButton);

TestUtils.Simulate.click(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(raisedButton).firstChild);

expect(myMock).toBeCalled();
```

It works fine for me. However I'm still struggling with Simulate.change

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Unfortunately TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(dialog, FlatButton) does not return anything in the dialog case.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem myself with Dialog.. Maybe an issue with Material UI's Dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

[Solution by avocadojesus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137996/5806646) is excellent. But I have one addition. If you try to apply this solution and get an error:

> ERROR: 'Warning: Failed context type: The context `muiTheme` is marked
>   as required in `DialogInline`, but its value is `undefined`.

You should modify his the code as follows:

```
var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <UserInteractions.signupDialog show={true}/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

var dialogComponent = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(component, UserInteractions.signupDialog);

var dialog = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    {dialogComponent.refs.dialog.renderLayer()}
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

var node = React.findDOMNode(dialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI fork the 2 enzyme methods. You need to use the `createMount` or the `createShallow` with dive option https://material-ui.com/guides/testing/#createmount-options-mount